# what kind of error this my First AspectJ

Tags: java

this is where i put all package and this is my code

```
Spring.XML

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy></aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
<bean name="triangle" class="edu.itmaranatha.model.Triangle">
    <property name="name" value="Triangle name"/>
</bean>

<bean name="circle" class="edu.itmaranatha.model.Circle">
    <property name="name" value="Circle name"/>
</bean>

<bean name="shapeService" class="edu.itmaranatha.service.ShapeService" autowire="byName" />

<bean name="logingAspect" class="edu.itmaranatha.service.aspect.LoggingAspect"/>


</beans>
```

the error is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:957)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:741)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at edu.itmaranatha.aopj.AopMain.main(AopMain.java:11)
```

What the error mean?

Answer (score 0):

`Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice` means that you don't have `org.aopalliance.aop.Advice` in your classpath. You need to add [aopalliance.jar](http://aopalliance.sourceforge.net/).